# Automatically add row when filling out previous row, "Those rows are out of bounds (line 8, file "Code") error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm in the middle of creating a proposal builder for a audio/visual company. The builder uses data validation drop downs in order to select from a list of equipment types (Audio, Lights, Electric, etc). Depending on what is chosen, the following data validated cell will drop down with sub-options for that type of equipment.

Some of these projects are rather large and require a lot of equipment, others are much smaller. I want to set it up so that when one piece of equipment is selected another row is created underneath it and allows for more options to be selected... the alternative to this would be either manually inserting a row and copying the formula of the previous row down or pre-filling out a bunch of rows that could potentially be selected which would risk having a bunch of extra rows (not the great for something that is going to be re-used hundreds of times)

I've tried the script below, which I was *hoping* would have added a row underneath the current row I was filling out (Row 40).
[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7NUR.png)

```
function addRows(){
  var startRow = 40;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

for (var i=numRows; i > -1; i--) {
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + startRow, 1);
  }
}
```

This script keeps giving me the "Those rows are out of bounds (line 8, file "Code") error.

Any ideas?

EDIT: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Running this script once will return an added row at the bottom, but it seems that every time I run it after that it doubles the amount of rows that are added.

1st run: 1 row is added
2nd run: 2 rows are added
3rd run: 4 rows are added
4th run: 8 rows are added

Is there something obvious in this script that is causing this to happen?

[Image after running it twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgP6h.png)

Comment: I only see six lines of code.   Please provide a [mcve].  It might also be useful to see a spreadsheet example.

Comment: I had just edited the OP to include the full code and a visual example of what I'm referring to. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany) throws that error (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsAfter(Integer,Integer))):

- first parameter is 0
- first parameter is larger than the number of rows that exist in that sheet. (as you could not insert after row 400 if your sheet doesn`t even have 400 rows).

By looking at your code it`s clear that this error is happening because of **your first parameter being larger than the number of rows in the sheet**.To show you how this is happening, here is a possible error case:

- Imagine you have 120 rows in your sheet and all are filled with data
- As your sheet is full, numRows = 120 `var numRows = rows.getNumRows();`
- When you go to your first loop iteration, you would have `sheet.insertRowsAfter(120 + startRow, 1);`
- This leads to script trying to insert 1 row after row 160, which doesn't even exists (is out of bonds).

I`m not sure if I actually got what was your plan with that code, especially with the for loop. But if you wanted to insert a row or N rows after that be simply something like that:

```
var startRow = 40;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

  sheet.insertRowsAfter(startRow , 1); //or any number N instead of 1
```